# Learning Lambda Calculus

Tags: logic, learning, online-resources, lambda-calculus, type-theory

What are some good online/free resources (tutorials, guides, exercises, and the like) for learning Lambda Calculus?

Specifically, I am interested in the following areas:

- Untyped lambda calculus
- Simply-typed lambda calculus
- Other typed lambda calculi
- Church's Theory of Types (I'm not sure where this fits in).

(As I understand, this should provide a solid basis for the understanding of type theory.)

Any advice and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 90):

[image: alligators]

[**Alligator Eggs**](http://worrydream.com/AlligatorEggs/) is a cool way to learn lambda calculus.

Also learning functional programming languages like Scheme, Haskell etc. will be added fun.

Comment: Hah, looks pretty funny. Maybe not the in-depth tutorial I'm looking for, but will have to check it out!

Comment: Looks really fun! I can use this to teach kids.

Comment: Now *that* I call a nice model of lambda calculus! I wonder what Dana Scott has to say about this ;-)

Comment: Alligator Eggs may be a cool way to teach it, but the site assumes you already have knowledge and you're trying to teach it to others who don't.

Answer (score 49):

Recommendations:

1. Barendregt & Barendsen, 1998, [Introduction to lambda-calculus](https://www.academia.edu/18746611/Introduction_to_lambda_calculus);
2. Girard, Lafont & Taylor, 1987, [Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/Proofs+Types.html);
3. Sørenson & Urzyczyn, 1999, [Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism](https://disi.unitn.it/%7Ebernardi/RSISE11/Papers/curry-howard.pdf).

All of these are mentioned in [the LtU Getting Started thread](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/492).

Comment: Thanks again Charles, that looks like good material.

Comment: Out of curiosity, will learning simply and then more advanced typed versions of lambda calculus give me a pretty good coverage of the field of type theory?

Comment: @Noldorin - Sorry for the long delay in replying... No, or rather it depends on what you mean by "more advanced typed versions of lambda calculus" - I think it is wiser in this case to work through seminal texts, rather than thinking of mastering the relevant formal systems directly.

Comment: Haha, only 7 years eh... better late than never, as they say! I've learnt a lot since then, but thank you.

Comment: @Noldorin You could write up your own answer to this question, maybe?

Comment: I'm still by no means an expert in this field. I don't think I could add much, to be honest. :)

Answer (score 41):

Here are a couple of resources that will get you started:

1. [The Lambda Calculus, Its Syntax and Semantics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444875085) - This is a must!
2. [Lecture Notes on the Lambda Calculus by Peter Selinger](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/papers/lambdanotes.pdf)
3. [History of Lambda Calculi](http://www.users.waitrose.com/~hindley/histlamconts.pdf)
4. [Impact of Lambda Calculus on Logic and Computer Science](http://enl.usc.edu/~jkna/fpl/church.pdf)
5. [Introduction to Lambda Calculus](http://homepages.nyu.edu/~cb125/Lambda/barendregt.94.pdf)
6. [Lambda Calculi with Types](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/barendregt.pdf)
7. [Tutorial Introduction to Lambda Calculus](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/ag-ki/rojas_home/documents/tutorials/lambda.pdf)
8. [Call-by-name, call-by-value and the Lambda Calculus](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/gdp/publications/cbn_cbv_lambda.pdf)
9. [Control operators, the SECD-machine, and

   the lambda-calculus.](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/pub/techreports/TR197.pdf)  - With effects
10. Modified basic functionality in combinatory logic- H.B. Curry.
11. The principal type scheme of an object in combinatory 
    logic. - J. Roger Hindley.

Since I am a computer science graduate, most of these are geared towards computer scientists rather than logicians.

Bonus : There is a new book that has come out [Semantics Engineering with PLT Redex](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262062755). I haven't read it but people have told me good things about it.

I hope this helps. Please feel free to ask me any questions. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the book by Henk P. Barendregt “The Lambda Calculus, Its Syntax and Semantics” is too formal to be useful as a first textbook to learn lambda calculus. I think it is more a reference book for people working in related fields.

Answer (score 18):

I like [Type Theory and Functional Programming](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/TTFP/) by Simon Thompson.

Answer (score 12):

It might be nice to work through *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*, which is [available online](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) for free. This book is an introduction to computer science and the programming language Scheme, which is a flavor of the programming language Lisp, which is based on the lambda calculus. Although it is not strictly a book about the lambda calculus, it might be fun or useful to gain some hands-on and "practical" experience with the lambda calculus by reading some of this book and working through some of its exercises.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm sure you're right in saying that it will provide an insight, though I am perhaps looking for a more theoretical approach (as Alonzo Church originally formulated it). I have some active experience in F# which should provide a basis.

Comment: This won't help much with understanding types.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I'm responding to your old comment, because I guess with the number of upvotes the original question makes for a good reference question, and your comment somehow has a rating of 7.  The question indicates an interest in untyped lambda calculus, so I don't see how your comment is relevant.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Untyped lambda calculus is just one thing the question asks for.  Mostly the question is after information about typed lambda calculus.

Answer (score 11):

Lambda-Calculus and Combinators, an Introduction by J. ROGER HINDLEY and JONATHAN P. SELDIN is a great (and relatively modern) resource that doesn't assume any previous knowledge.

It is available online [here](http://mmcs.sfedu.ru/~ulysses/CS/Lambda/Hindley,%20Seldin.%20Lambda-calculus%20and%20Combinators.pdf).

Answer (score 11):

[image: lol]

[**To Dissect a Mockingbird**: A Graphical Notation for the Lambda Calculus with Animated Reduction](http://dkeenan.com/Lambda/) by David C Keenan is a nice complement to **Alligator Eggs** given above. Keenan uses [Smullyan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Smullyan)'s bird metaphors from [*To Mock a Mockingbird*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Mock_a_Mockingbird) and augments them with diagram notation, which aids in building intuition around combinators. The above is Y combinator in Keenan's notation.

Answer (score 5):

I found this iPhone app that works as an un-typed lambda calculator, it works with  successor, addition, addition with successor, multiplication, exponentiation, predecessor and subtraction operations. It shows a step by step process which might be helpful for people who are just starting with lambda calculus.

link: https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=928503408&mt=8

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago, I was surprised not to find many untyped & simply-typed lambda calculus **interpreters** among the answers to this question, so I started working for a while in an educational lambda calculus interpreter called [Mikrokosmos](https://github.com/mroman42/mikrokosmos) (can also be used [online](https://mroman42.github.io/mikrokosmos/)). It implements untyped and simply typed lambda calculus (and also illustrates Curry-Howard).

Surely, you could also use some functional programming language; but at least for me, it was difficult to determine exactly which constructs of the language are *lambda calculus* and which are *extras* offered by that particular language. Haskell for instance approximately implements System-F, but I also wanted to have a simply(as simple as possible)-typed lambda calculus interpreter.

The interpreter is free software and you can integrate them on other learning materials (such as [Jupyter notebooks](https://github.com/mroman42/jupyter-mikrokosmos/) or [web pages](https://github.com/mroman42/mikrokosmos-js/)). I have used it before to teach lambda calculus to CS students.

*[Please note that I am the main developer of this interpreter.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers/59302#59302) I am only posting here because this same question inspired me to start the development.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat different suggestion from the others.  I first learned how $\lambda$-calculus worked from *Functional Programming* by Field and Harrison.  Most of the book is about other topics, but I think the $\lambda$-calculus part stands on its own.

It explains all the essential parts, briefly, and from the standpoint that the $\lambda$-calculus will be used as a target language for compiling functional programming languages.  This means that they give close attention to the issue of how one uses $\lambda$-terms to represent specific computations.  I found this computational approach pleasantly concrete.

Reading this got me the basics, and prepared me well to pursue the more comprehensive sources (like Barendregt) afterward.