# Book on lambda calculus logic and type theory

Tags: reference-request, logic, computability, lambda-calculus, type-theory

Can someone recommend me a book for self study which will cover topics of logic, lambda calculus and type theory. I know about "Computability and Logic" written by Bolos but it describe recursive function as a model of computation and does no cove type theory.

If there is no singe book I would like to read some book which would build a bridge between those topics.

Comment: Did you take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967)? It seems that many references there could help you further. Perhaps it can even be considered a duplicate?

Comment: I loved "Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism" by Sørensen and Urzyczyn, but it's possible that it will assume too much of the lambda-calculus background. You might try it and see.

Comment: @Lord_Farin question you pointed is specifically about lambda calculus and I am asking about connection between logic and computability (lambda calculus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some good book on those topics. This book has exercises with solution so it is perfect for self studying. The book is  "Lambda-Calculus and Combinators an Introduction" by J. Roger Hindley, Jonathan P. Seldin. Link for more info http://www.cambridge.org/us/knowledge/isbn/item1175709/?site_locale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

I found this a valuable and concise introduction:

> [The Seven Virtues of Simple Type Theory](http://imps.mcmaster.ca/doc/seven-virtues.pdf) by William M. Farmer.

Answer (score 1):

Being a programmer the one I am recommending is more of a programming book but does cover lambda calculus and type theory. [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/439279797) by Benjamin C. Pierce. I am not sure what you mean by logic in this question so I am not saying the book covers logic, but am pretty sure it will cover what you need.

For the list of lambda type systems covered see: [λ-Calculus extensions: meaning of extension symbols](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9548/268)

Comment: I have read some parts of "Types and Programming Languages" by Benjamin C. Pierce. It explained more practical aspects (if you can say so about lambda-calculus) of lambda-calculus and I have to admin it was quite good.