# Mathematically rigorous books on programming and computer science

Tags: reference-request

I would like a mathematical approach to programming languages and computer science, not just the theoretical aspects of computer science. Is there any such text out there? After all, the world has a huge supply of mathematical texts.

Comment: I wish there was a community on non math books that have a nice math-y style. I find it really hard to read non mathematical introductory stuff (like electronics). Some of it feels extremely ambiguous to me and i believe most of it could be remedied with precise definitions and stuff like that.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're looking for? There are certainly math-oriented books on computer science (both theoretical and applied), but I don't think you'll find something like "Java for Mathematicians." (Nor do I know what that would entail; software engineering is more about organization and procedures and memorizing the niceties of various languages than any real science or math.) Or are you looking for a mathematical treatment of programming languages and parsing, compilation, etc. in general?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a mathematical treatment of programming languages, parsing, compilation, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like a mathematical approach to programming languages and computer science, not just the theoretical aspects of computer science.

This sounds like you want a more formal book about programming languages themselves from a mathematical perspective, rather than the more standard "undergrad" CS theory (algorithmics, complexity theory, data structures analysis, etc...).

I think, however, it is very useful to know the basics of computability theory (automata, regular languages, Turing machines, Lambda calculus, context-free grammars, etc...), before looking at this area. Understanding compilers/interpreters deeply also requires it. (PS: for many graduate CS courses at most major universities, they have a publicly available syllabus/website with book recommendations present; it can be useful to check them).

Anyway, many mathematical treatments of programming languages tend to come from a [*type theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) and [*lambda calculus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) approach, which allow formalizing programming and the language itself. This is particularly prevalent among introductions to [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) languages (a fact which [may not be appreciated by all its would-be users](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103776/why-are-all-the-functional-programming-tutorials-so-mathy?rq=1)).

Two popular books that somewhat follow this approach are:

- [*Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce](https://www.amazon.ca/Types-Programming-Languages-Benjamin-Pierce/dp/0262162091)
- [*An Introduction to Functional Programming Through Lambda Calculus* by Michaelson](https://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Functional-Programming-Calculus-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00CWR4USM)

Note that the former book does not neglect Object-Oriented Programming.
There are also other angles to look at, however, which tend more formalized from a logic perspective, such as [operational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics) (e.g., [this book](https://www.amazon.ca/Programming-Languages-Operational-Semantics-Overview/dp/1447163672/)).

Related: 
[[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403835/book-on-lambda-calculus-logic-and-type-theory?noredirect=1&lq=1), 
[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory),
[[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862220/curry-howard-for-an-imperative-programming-language),
[[4]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431482/type-theory-as-foundations).

Answer (score 1):

How about "The art of computer programming" by Donald Knuth?